# Is the support of the differential of a k-form a subset of the support of the k-form?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm finishing up a self-study of Munkres's *Analysis on Manifolds* and ran across this claim:

> Let $\omega$ be a $(k-1)$-form defined on an open set of $R^{n}$ containing a compact oriented $k$-manifold $M$ (for $k>1$). Then the support of $d\omega$ is contained in the support of $\omega$.

Is there a simple way to prove this?

Having a hard time treating the case where $x \in R^{n}$ is a limit point of the support of $d\omega$, rather than simply a point of $R^{n}$ at which $d\omega(x)$ is non-zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be easier to work with complements here: show that whenever $\omega$ is zero, so is $d\omega$.

Comment: Your suggestion does the trick. Many thanks.

Comment: Albert, it would be nice if you wrote an answer to this question. Then anyone ever searching for it will have something to find!

Comment: Great idea. Will do.

Comment: I've finally found a question on this! I think it's related to local operator or support-decreasing? See [support-decreasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XI7V.png), [local operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uiz.png), [anti/derivations are local operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z09Es.png) from An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. @SteveD

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof.

Note that if $\omega$ is a differential form, which is $0$ on some open set $U$, then $d\omega=0$ on $U$ as well (the answer by Albert essentially shows this).

Now let $p$ be a point outside $\text{supp}(\omega)$, and $U$ an open set around $p$ that is disjoint from $\text{supp}(\omega)$.  Then $\omega=0$ on $U$, and by the previous paragraph, $d\omega=0$ on $U$ as well. Thus $p$ is also not in $\text{supp}(d\omega)$.  It's easy to see this implies $\text{supp}(d\omega) \subset \text{supp}(\omega)$.

Comment: Is this related to [support-decreasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XI7V.png), [local operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uiz.png), [anti/derivations are local operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z09Es.png) from An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, any (*k-1*)-form $\omega$ can be represented as

> (1) $\omega$ = $\sum_{[I]}^{}$ $f_{I} dx_{I}$,

for *I* = {$i_{1}$, … , $i_{k-1}$} an ascending (*k-1*)-tuple from the set {*1, … , n*}; $f_{I}$ a $0$-form defined on $R^{n}$; and $dx_{I}$ = $dx_{i_{1}} \wedge ... \wedge dx_{i_{k-1}}$, where $dx_{i}$ is the elementary 1-form $\tilde{{\phi}_{i}}$ in $R^{n}$. The symbol [*I*] indicates that the summation extends over all ascending (k-1)-tuples from the set {*1, … , n*}.

Suppose *x* $\notin$ Support $\omega$. Then $\omega(x) = 0$ on all (*k-1*)-tuples ((*x*; $v_{1}$), ...,(*x*; $v_{k-1}$)), $v_{i} \in R^{n}$. It's easy to show that $\omega(x) = 0$ implies each of the $f_{I}$ in (1) equals zero. For example, suppose *k* = 4 and *n* = 5. To show that $f_{(1,2,5)}= 0$, evaluate the right-hand side of (1) on the 3-tuple of vectors ((*x*; $e_{1}$), (*x*; $e_{2}$), (*x*; $e_{5}$)).

That each of the $f_{I}$ equals $0$ implies that

> (2) *d*$\omega$ =  $\sum_{[I]}^{}$ $df_{I} \wedge $ $dx_{I}$

also equals zero for this choice of *x*.

We've established that

> (3) *d*$\omega$(*x*) $\neq  0 \Rightarrow\omega(x) \neq 0$.

From (3) it follows directly that *Closure* $\big(\{x|d\omega(x)\neq 0\}\big)$ $\subset$ *Closure* $\big(\{x|\omega(x) \neq 0\}\big)$.

Comment: The bit you call "easy to show" is actually the whole point of the problem. In fact $\omega_p$ does not imply that the functions are identically zero locally. There are lots of functions which vanish at a point, but their derivatives do not!

Comment: @PVAL-inactive Thanks for your comment. While it's true that a function can vanish at a point and still have a non-zero derivative at that point, ω(x), a (k-1)-tensor on R^n, vanishes at ALL (k-1)-tuples of elements of the tangent space to R^n at x. Could you help me understand where I might have gone wrong with this particular problem? I provided a method for showing that each of the component functions--i.e., each of the f_I--equals zero ("For example, suppose k = 4 and n = 5 ..."). Each of the f_I is a 0-form, so each of the df_I is identically zero (df = (D_1f)dx_1 + ... +
 (D_nf)dx_n).

Comment: @Albert: try your approach with the point $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\omega=f\ dx$, with $f(x,y)=y$.

Comment: @SteveD I’ll try, though I’m feeling WAY out of my depth here. If ω(x) = 0 on all (x;v_1), then ω(x) = f(x) dx = 0 on (x; e_1), which implies that f(x) = 0 since dx(x; e_1) = 1. So I  would say that f(x,y) _cannot_ equal y: We can’t independently specify ω and f. Once we constrain ω to equal 0 on all (x;v_1), then, by (1), f can’t take on any value we choose.

Comment: BTW, happy to see a better/real proof of the original statement: "Let ω be a (k−1)-form defined on an open set of R^n containing a compact oriented k-manifold M (for k>1). Then the support of dω is contained in the support of ω." I'm not proud :-)

Comment: @albert, I think you're varying the actual point (not just the vectors), and I'm not sure why?

Comment: @SteveD, differential forms are new to me and I have only a layman's grasp of them, so apologies ahead of time if I misunderstand your question (again). As a differential form -- let's say it's of order k -- the value of ω(x) is actually a k-tensor defined on the tangent space to R^n at x. ω(x) is a particular k-tensor that can be represented uniquely as per equation (1), above, where (f_I)(x) is function from R^n to R, aka a "0-form." To say that ω(x) = 0 is to say that the corresponding k-tensor (the RHS of eq (1)) is zero on all k-tuples from the tangent space to R^n at x.  [continued] ...

Comment: The Support of ω (the subject of my original question) is the set of all x for which ω(x) is not identically zero. If ω(x) is identically zero, this means that the right-hand side of (1) evaluates to zero on all possible k-tuples from the tangent space to R^n at x. I take advantage of this fact to show that each component function (f_I)(x) is actually the zero function. (I can do this by strategically selecting a k-tuple that zeroes out all but one of the (f_I)(x), as per the example I gave.) -- Anyway, all help is welcome since I'm more befuddled now than when I posed the original Q.

Comment: ... BTW, it's the k-tensor dx_I in the formula (1) that takes the k-tuple of vectors from the tangent space to R^n at x as arguments. In the example above, I show that f_(1,2,5) = 0 by evaluating the RHS of (1) on the 3-tuple of vectors ((x; e_1), (x; e_2), (x; e_5)). All the dx_I evaluate to zero on this 3-tuple except dx_(1,2,5) which evaluates to 1. Thus I conclude that ω(x) = 0 = (f_(1,2,5))(x). Same goes for all the f_I.

Comment: I think your terminology is confusing: at a single point, the differential form is a linear combination of $dx_I$ (so that the coefficients are constant numbers, not functions).  In a chart, then yes, the form is a combination of $f_Idx_I$, where the $f_I$ are smooth functions. So when $\omega(x)=0$, $f_I(x)=0$ for all $I$, as you've shown.  But that **does not** mean $f_I$ is the zero function. As in the example I gave, if $\omega = ydx$, then at the point $p=(0,0)$, $\omega(p)=0$. However, $d\omega(p)=dy\wedge dx\neq0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62475/discussion-between-albert-and-steve-d).

Comment: Is this related to [support-decreasing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XI7V.png), [local operator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uiz.png), [anti/derivations are local operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z09Es.png) from An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu?